# Contract deployment out of gas, but was created anyway?

Tags: contract-deployment, parity, out-of-gas, kovan

I have `deployed` a `contract` with `Parity` on `Kovan`, which did not show up in the `contracts menu` after `contract deployment` was done. I had to `watch` it manually to be able to see it in the `contracts menu`.

When I check the contract on Etherscan, it tells me `Contract Creation` `Out of Gas`, but the contract was deployed anyway!?

[image: Contract deployment with error]
My questions are:

1. How could it be deployed if it was out of gas?
2. If errors were encountered during contract creation, is it still fully functional?

Comment: What's the tx hash? It should not be deployed.

Comment: 0x0921f6cb3827622bed0d854e6514d69b4e3e4976b04d84033d842c9a6d39d4bc

Comment: It hasn't been deployed. The [code](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x33fe746089e10308f18b05903348a8ac8f36e2f1#code) is empty

Comment: This is confusing. Why it was mined then and did not gave me an error instead?

Comment: A tx that fails during execution will still be mined, and you still have to pay for the gas consumed, but any state changes done by it will be reverted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. How could it be deployed if it was out of gas?**

If you take a look at Section 7.1 of the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) it states that *"while the initialisation code is executing, the newly created address exists but with no intrinsic body code"*.

**2. If errors were encountered during contract creation, is it still fully functional?**

Shortly after it states that *"For a normal STOP code, or if the code returned is otherwise empty, then the state is left with a zombie account, and any remaining balance will be locked into the account forever"*

So no, your contract is not fully functional.